# How to cut/paste in Visual Studio 2010 with Emacs emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I downloaded the emacs emulator for Visual Studio 2010, and everything seems to work fine and dandy -- except cut and paste!

I can delete regions by setting a mark (CTRL-Space) and then delete it with CTRL-W.  But it seems that it never goes to the kill ring -- if I try CTRL-Y to yank it, then nothing happens.

Curiously enough, if I delete a line with CTRL-K, then the deleted line goes to the kill ring.

Visual Studio's keybinding menus suggest that CTRL-W should be cut and CTRL-Y should be paste, so this seems to be something wrong with the emulator.

Has anyone had a similar problem, or know how to cut/paste with emacs emulation on?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug and Microsoft has declined to fix it.  See: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/672582/emacs-mode-cut-copy-paste-errors

This is the bug that I submitted.  At one point I had Ctrl-w/Ctrl-y working internal to Visual Studio, but never externally.  I was fiddling with exporting/importing settings and it started working.  Now I've had to reset Visual Studio and it's not working again, and no amount of fiddling will get it back to where I was.  Sigh.

So whenever I have to do some serious cut/paste work, especially between the code and some other window, I just save the file in VS and open up Emacs, do the editing in Emacs, then save the file in Emacs. When I go back to VS it asks if I want to reload the file.  A click on "Yes" in I'm back working in VS, ready to compile or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that dragging and dropping text selections from other applications, into VS2010 with the emacs package installed, DOES work.  Your mileage may vary.